# How do I delay the custom processing of emails to a specified time as set in the Send Delay rule in Outlook?

Tags: c#, email, outlook, outlook-addin

Currently, when a Sender clicks Send after composing an email, my Outlook Add-in (created with VSTO) will send the email to a 3rd party repository for processing. If it is successfully verified, the add-in will send it out to the recipient. If not, the email will be kept in Draft.

**Issue**

When the Sender sets a [Send Delay](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/delay-or-schedule-sending-email-messages-026af69f-c287-490a-a72f-6c65793744ba) rule of a few days and clicks Send, the Recipient will already be able to see the incoming email in their 3rd party repository (if they are registered as a user of the repository) before it is scheduled to arrive in their email client. This is because the 3rd party repository also acts as a kind of email client and currently the process is to send the email to the 3rd party repository before sending it out from Outlook.

**Questions**

Since these processing are currently handled in the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_Event's` [Send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemevents_event.send?view=outlook-pia) and `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application's` [ItemSend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.applicationclass.itemsend?view=outlook-pia) events, is it possible to delay these events until the email is scheduled to be sent out?

Answer (score 1):

If SendDelay is set, all email messages should be in the Draft folder (for example). You need an background wroker who frequently checks the messages to be sent.(may be a task treggered by any event)

This way, as a user, I can still delete the message before sending it at the scheduled time.